# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string error with URL conversion

Tags: php, json

I have the following code segment, which produces the two lines of output shown.

The `json_decode` fails with the above error. I cannot work out why.

```
...
$url=curl_exec($curl);

echo $url.'<br><br>';
var_dump($url);
echo json_decode($url);

{"url":"http:\/\/www.someurl.com\/?i=228415137384187126&p=START&v=h1-e1-z1-dbds-m1-b1-"}

string(88) "{"url":"http:\/\/www.someurl.com\/?i=228415137384187126&p=START&v=h1-e1-z1-dbds-m1-b1-"}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_decode()` used in this way will return a `stdClass` object. You should not try to `echo` it, but instead do this:

```
$url=curl_exec($curl);
$decoded_url_object = json_decode($url);
echo $decoded_url_object->url;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was missing the ->url bit. I was trying to link directly to the decoded result.

Comment: `json_decode()` does not crash the script with the URL you provided - I've just tested it myself. If it could not decode it, it would return NULL instead of throwing fatal error. The problem is that you're trying to `echo` something that is not `echoable`, at least in normal circumstances. You have an object, and it has properties. You want to `echo` a property of the object, not the object itself.